# A question about possible differences between plane and spherical geometry

Tags: geometry

Are the theorems about Brocard points and the Brocard angle of plane triangles also true for spherical triangles?

Comment: Difficult to answer if we do not know which theorems you are referring to. The existence of two isogonal-conjugated points? The fact that $\cot\omega=\cot\alpha+\cot\beta+\cot\gamma$?

Comment: I am referring to the theorems which state the existence of two Brocard points in any plane triangle and which express the Brocard angle as a function of the angles of that plane triangle.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: The theorems you mention are exactly the theorems I have in mind.  However I would not be surprised if-in the case of a spherical triangle-the Brocard angle (assuming it exists) was a slightly different function of the angles of the triangle than the function corresponding to the "cotangent formula" for plane triangles.

Comment: Then we just need to understand how Ceva's theorem works for spherical triangles. [This](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2004-12/9288.html) may be relevant.